# Getting pytest to see the file that I want tested

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a folder called `my_server`.
Inside, there is a `server.py` file, and a folder called `tests` that contains `test_server.py` which is actually the pytest file.

I am having trouble getting pytest to see the my_server.py file, in both native and docker environments.

I use this line to declare the `my_server` file to pytest:

```
from my_server.server import app
```

Since `server.py` lives under the `my_server` folder, i declared it that way.
However, i get this error:

```
    from my_server.server import app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_server'
```

What's more is that the folder's name is hardcoded this way.
When i move to a docker environment and mount the files, then there is no `my_server` folder, but all the files live under the folder called `imported_files`.

And i get the same error.

So what is the correct way to make pytest see the file that i want to be tested?

Comment: Please, specify the way you run pytest

Comment: I enter the command `pytest` from `my_server` directory (natively). In docker terms this folder does not exist, but it is named `imported_files`, so i run the `pytest` command from here.

Comment: The error can be fixed either by changing pytest command and path you run command from, or by setting PYTHONPATH sys variable to the parent folder of my_server. In your case, try to call: PYTHONPATH=../ pytest from the same directory

Comment: Thanks, but i am confused. Is there a way to just change the command directory, instead of using environment variables?

Comment: Of course, you can run command from the parent directory of `my_server`